# How do I write inline documentation for methods and variables in Go code?

Tags: go, documentation

is there some rules to document methods and variables in GO language?

for example on php

```
/**
 This method will increase parameter $b in 10 points
 @var int $b
 @return int

*/
public function someMethod($b){
    return $b+10;
}
```

is there something like that on GO, or there I must use only "// comment" above method without any @var or @return ?

Comment: You just use descriptive names (i.e. not `someMethod` or `b`). godoc copies text from documentation comments verbatim.

Comment: @rightfold thanks for your reply, but I am not sure that correctly understood you. Can you please describe it more detailed?

Answer (score 12):

You should use standard // comments because this is what the official documentation tool called godoc will use to generate documentation for your go code. You can have a look at this post from the official golang blog about it: http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code

I also found this quite interesting: https://godoc.org/github.com/natefinch/godocgo

Comment: June 2022 - Official Go guild line updated: https://go.dev/doc/comment

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard //  and the first word must be the name of function  package (for generator) .

golang  doc :

> Notice this comment is a complete sentence that begins with the name
> of the element it describes. This important convention allows us to
> generate documentation